# PHP shell_exec() result in txt file?

Tags: php, file, text-files, shell-exec

I'd like to try to see the output of two shell_exec() calls in a .txt file.So i tried this:

```
$data_server = shell_exec('./c5.0demo -f $username -r');
$errorFile = "error.txt";
$fileopen = fopen($errorfile, 'w') or die ("can't open file");
fwrite($fileopen, $data_server);

$data_server2 = shell_exec('./predictBatch -f $username -r > $username.result');
$fileopen = fopen($errorfile, 'w') or die ("can't open file");
fwrite($fileopen, $data_server2);
```

The executable "c5.0demo" and "predictBatch" are in the same directory of this PHP's script.
The variable $username is retrieved by POST method: $user = $_POST['username'];
Being an array i put the value inside another variable by this:

```
 foreach($user as $val)
 $username .= $val;
```

I think this is correct but i don't have "error.txt" inside my directory. 
Why am i wrong?
Thanks for all your support!

Comment: I'm wondering if your arguments that use expanded variables are at least part of the problem: `'./predictBatch -f $username -r > $username.result'` should be `"./predictBatch -f $username -r > $username.result"` (note `"` instead of `'`). This also goes for the first line. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Tnx Jared. If i change ' in " it doesn't work. It doesn't create error.txt file. I was thinking: it is possible i have to specify the directory where create that file?

Comment: Specifying an absolute path would be a good troubleshooting step. It could be a permission issue, that the process running the file doesn't have write permission for the directory.

Comment: I got it! It was $errorFile and $errorfile. Damn case sensitive!!! :D

Comment: Ok this is the definition of unsafe coding. Use escapeshellarg() on your $username variable or someone could compromise your server by passing a ';<command to execute as web server>' on his username.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$data_server = shell_exec("./c5.0demo -f $username -r");
$data_server2 = shell_exec("./predictBatch -f $username -r > $username.result");

file_put_contents("/path/to/log/error.txt","{$data_server} : {$data_server2}\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Obviously $username needs to be defined - also, what is the datatype of $username? I ask, because $username.result looks very wrong.

You should also take very **serious** note of @mobius warning.